# Altcoin based on Litecoin

Tags: litecoin, altcoin, altcoin-development

I've compiled the Litecoin source using a custom genesis block to create a simple Altcoin for fun.

I just have some questions about Bitcoin/Litecoin Qt.

1. When I mine a block using the `generate` command, Litecoin Qt doesn't seem to inform any of its peers, either that or the peers aren't picking up the mined block. Does anyone know why?
2. I modified the DNS seeds to use my own domain name instead of Litecoin's, except Litecoin Qt can't seem to use my domain name to find nodes. The domain just returns a list of A records pointing to potential peers. Have I set that up correctly?
3. Litecoin Qt also can't seem to download the blocks from it's peers the first time it launches, does anyone know why?
4. The blockchain based on my custom genesis block doesn't seem to sync, does anyone have any idea why?

I haven't modified any of the source code apart from changing the genesis block.

I have Litecoin Qt on my local machine and two VPS's hosting two nodes. My first thought was that maybe I need more than two full nodes to get things working?